# algorithm to either fit data as linear or stepwise constant

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cart, change-point

Given data $(y_i, x_i)_{i=1}^n$, I wish to fit either:

1. a linear regression, $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$; or
2. a stepwise constant function, $y = \left\{ 
       \begin{align} 
         y_1 & \text{ if } x < \xi_1 \newline
         y_2 & \text{ if } x \in \left[ \xi_1, \xi_2 \right) \newline
         \vdots \newline
         y_n & \text{ if } x \ge \xi_{n-1}    
       \end{align} \right\}$.

Is there a single algorithm that can determine whether the linear regression (fitting $\beta_0, \beta_1$) or the stepwise constant function (fitting $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_{n-1}$) is a better fit (for a given computational budget)?

Note:

1. the stepwise constant function is a linear regression with zero slope but structural breaks;
2. the stepwise constant function can be produced by e.g.\ XGBoost with `max_depth = 1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "single algorithm"? Why don't you just use the one with less loss, e.g. mean squared error?

Comment: by `single algorithm', I mean that I run one command, and it simultaneously determines which function to fit (linear or piecewise constant) as well as the corresponding parameters in order to minimise loss.

Comment: It seems you are looking for spline regression.

Comment: There is a *huge* number of such algorithms.  I recall finding over 100 packages for this listed on CRAN some four years ago when I last surveyed the possibilities.  Please, then, clarify your question by providing more details of your data and your objectives.

Comment: @whuber Would you mind posting two examples and what your search term was? Thanks.

Comment: @cdalitz A subset of them is discussed at https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/packages.html, found by Googling "CRAN changepoint".

Comment: @cdalitz: I don't think I want a spline: unless I'm mistaken, they're non-linear and continuous, so don't correspond to either of the two models that I'd like to choose between.

Comment: @whuber: I know a lot of algorithms for estimating particular relationships specifically, but none that give me this choice.  Among those that you mention, could you say which seems most relevant?

Comment: @colin-rowat "they're non-linear" The R function `bs` has an option `degree`. I just noticed, though, that the smallest allowed value is 1, so they can be linear, but not non-continuous. You are thus right that they cannot emulate piecewise constant functions. The term *changepoint* suggested by whuber is apparently what you ar looking for. You can compare models by the larger $R^2$ (or the smaller MSE), which both are in-sample criteria, or by a smaller AIC (which asymptotically is an out-of-sample criterium).

Comment: thanks @cdalitz. From what I understand of CRAN's 'changepoint', it detects structural breaks/changepoints rather than estimating step function.  Agreed, once I can estimate a step function, I can compare it to a linear regression and pick the better.  I wondered if there was a more efficient both-in-all procedure.

Comment: A step function represents a subset of possible forms of structural change.